# Coverting INT to decimal following mm.ss format

Tags: c#, math, type-conversion

I may be being really stupid here, but my brain's gone blank.

I've got a slider bar (which uses Int32 values) but I want to use it to select a position in a music song (mm.ss)

I also want to output the value that the slider is displaying in to a label above it, so it's easier to see what the slider is set to.

Anyone have any suggestions?

I thought of trying to convert the int value in to a decimal then dividing by 60.

I'm doing this in C# by the way.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your time and help. Jon Skeet your method worked out really well. Apart from ToString() didn't like the parameters, it complained about not taking any, but without the @"mm\.ss" it still worked quite well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What does the `int` value represent? If it's the number of seconds through the song, you should use:

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
string text = time.ToString(@"mm\.ss");
```

Using a `decimal` would be a really bad idea - a format with a number of seconds isn't the same as a fractional number of minutes. For example, 10.50 minutes *as a fractional number of minutes* is 10 minutes and 30 seconds, not 10 minutes and 50 seconds, which is what you want as far as I can tell.

`TimeSpan` is the *natural* way of representing a time duration in .NET... which is why that's the type which supports [formatting in minutes and seconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Converting it into decimal would not display it the way that you want it. For example four and an half minute would display as 4:50, not 4:30.

Divide the time into minutes and seconds, and format them:

```
int minutes = time / 60;
int seconds = time % 60;
string formatted = minutes.ToString() + ":" + seconds.ToString("00");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should represent the length of the song internally as seconds (which can be saved in an int). To actually display it, you do `song_length / 60` to get the minutes (this is called integer division, it returns the result and discards the fraction, e.g. `100/60 = 1`).

After that, you can get the seconds by `song_length % 60` (`%` is the modulo operator).

Edit: didn't see the c# tag. Jon Skeet's answer is more appropiate in c#.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I misunderstood the scope of the question, but I'll leave this in case it's helpful.

1. Store the total length of the track in seconds.
2. Calculate the position of the slider as a fraction of the maximum possible slider value.
3. Multiply the track length (in seconds) with fractional value obtained in 2).  This gives the offset from the start of the track in seconds.
4. Format the value from 3) for display.

Here is a contrived example to illustrate the process:

```
int maxSliderValue = 100;
int sliderValue = 18;
int trackLengthInSeconds = 248;

float sliderFraction = ((float)sliderValue)/((float)maxSliderValue);
int offsetInSeconds = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(trackLengthInSeconds * sliderFraction));
TimeSpan offset = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(offsetInSeconds);
string displayValue = offset.ToString(@"mm\.ss");
```